# Merging keys and values from hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash with the number of occurrences of cities from a model and I want to merge `nil` or `blank` keys and values into one and rename the new single key

for example

```
@raw_data = {nil => 2, "" => 2, "Berlin" => 1, "Paris" => 1}
# to
@corrected_data = {"undefined" => 4, "Berlin" => 1, "Paris" => 1}
```

I have looked into the merge method from the Rubydoc but it only merges if two keys are similar, but in this case `nil` and `""` are not the same.

I could also create a new hash and add `if nil or blank` statements and add the values to a new `undefined` key, but it seems tedious.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge nil or blank keys and values"?

Comment: in Ruby `nil` and `""` are not the same. In a Rails App when you create a user from a form and don't input any value then it will return `""` blank in the database. But if you create a User from the console or from a Cron then if you don't input the value it will return nil. Unless you create a default `""` or blank in the schema.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge nil or blank keys and values"?

Comment: You should normalize the form input in your controller or model, i.e. change empty strings to `nil` before creating the record

Comment: @Stefan yes that was just an example. I really wanted to understand the Hash mechanics because having blank and nil keys can happen (unexpectedly?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do :

```
@raw_data = {nil => 2, "" => 2, "Berlin" => 1, "Paris" => 1}
key_to_merge = [nil, ""]

@correct_data = @raw_data.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |(k,v), out_hash|
  next out_hash['undefined'] += v if key_to_merge.include? k
  out_hash[k] = v
end

@correct_data # => {"undefined"=>4, "Berlin"=>1, "Paris"=>1}
```

Comment: Your method works great, thank you! So in the end, there is no magic method from Ruby to combine two keys. Verifying the key name using the `include?` method through an array is brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

Ruby cannot automatically determine what do you want to do with values represented by two "similar" keys. You have to define the mapping yourself. One approach would be:

```
def undefined?(key)
  # write your definition of undefined here
  key.nil? || key.length == 0
end

def merge_value(existing_value, new_value)
  return new_value if existing_value.nil?
  # your example seemed to add values
  existing_value + new_value
end

def corrected_key(key)
  return "undefined" if undefined?(key)
  key
end

@raw_data = {nil => 2, "" => 2, "Berlin" => 1, "Paris" => 1}

@raw_data.reduce({}) do |acc, h|
  k, v = h
  acc[corrected_key(k)] = merge_value(acc[corrected_key(k)], v)
  acc
end

# {"undefined" => 4, "Berlin" => 1, "Paris" => 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, the combination of these methods work too. I like the `undefined?` method that could be used elsewhere. I need to dig a bit to understand what `reduce` does ;).

Comment: `reduce` is also known as `inject`.  You can read more about reduce here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduce_(higher-order_function)